# .NET ToolStripMenuItem check tick not visible in high contrast theme

Tags: c#, .net, controls, accessibility

Few users of our software was using high contrast theme in Windows for accessibility reasons and those users can't see checked state in ToolStripMenuItem because check tick is same color as background:

This is in normal Windows theme:

[image]

and this is in high contrast Windows Theme:

[image]

Is there a way to make check state visible in high contrast themes without use custom tick images as workaround?

Is this intentional or bug in this .NET control? Because all default .NET controls properly support high contrast theme as I can see, except this one.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find how to render check properly especially when there is image. But instead found workaround which is handy for image checked states in normal theme too because check is not easy to see when there is image in each items:

```
public class ToolStripCheckedBoldRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is ToolStripMenuItem && ((ToolStripMenuItem)e.Item).Checked)
        {
            e.TextFont = new Font(e.Item.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        }

        base.OnRenderItemText(e);
    }
}
```

`tsMain.Renderer = new ToolStripCheckedBoldRenderer();`

This renderer makes checked items bold text:

[image] [image]

So this solution is better than nothing but still need better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a .NET bug, fixed on .NET version 4.7.2 as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.6.2-4.7.2#accessibility-improvements-in-windows-forms-controls

quote:

> ToolStripMenuItem controls with their Checked property set to true now render the associated check mark in a contrasting system color. Previously the check mark color was not contrasting enough and not visible in High Contrast themes. NOTE: Windows 10 has changed values for some high contrast system colors. Windows Forms Framework is based on the Win32 framework. For the best experience, run on the latest version of Windows and opt in to the latest OS changes by adding an app.manifest file in a test application and un-commenting the following code:
>
> ```
> <!-- Windows 10 --> 
> <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
> ```